# Android go to next page

Tags: android

Im new to Android and I have created an app with 2 basic pages.
I am trying to work out how to go to the second page.
I have set the listener in the XML file, but do not know the command to make it go to the next page. My code is as follows:

```
public class Page2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page2);
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {

    }     
}
```

Comment: use intent to move from one page to next page.you have to create two Activity class.

Comment: Exactly when, do you want to go to that `page`?

Comment: welcome!! in android its called activity or fragment not pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From one Activity to another activity you can use `Intent`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in your first activity

```
bt_register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_register);

         bt_register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

use intent to move from one activity to next activity.you have to create two Activity class.

**Activity 1**

```
public class Page1 extends Activity {
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_page1);

bt_nextscreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_nextscreen);

     bt_nextscreen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Intent intent = new Intent(page1.this,page2.class);
         startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

**Activity 2**

```
public class Page2 extends Activity {
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_page2);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write below lines in your First Screen's Click event like if you want to show Screen2 on button press then paste this lines in Screen1's button click event.

```
startActivity (new intent (getApplicationContext(),Screen2.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

first add a button in layout(xml file) then add refrenece to its corresponding java file like this

```
next_button= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

then use this code to start activity

```
next_button.setOnclickListener(new OnClickListener(){

     startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), your_second_activity.class));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
         startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class));
       }
   });


}
```